# Include JSON file to build/output directory without import

Tags: json, typescript, tsconfig

Maybe the title is a bit strange, but I can't seem to find anything about on google.

**Question**: I have a folder that only contains .ts files and .json files.. Typescript compiles the .ts files and puts it into a separate directory (not as a bundle, just the directory structure 'as-is').

Src /

Workers /

[ModuleA.ts, ModuleA.json],

[ModuleB.ts, ModuleB.json],

[MobuleC.ts, ModuleC.json]

Most of the time I can just require('*.json') and the JSON file will be also placed in to build directory.

But now I have a situation, where importing the JSON will make no sense, because the JSON file gets updated every few seconds and I read the file with fs.readFile('*.json'), so I also don't want it floating around in the v8 cache (through require)

So how do I 'include' a JSON/None-Typescript file into the build, that is not explicitly being importing by either require or import?

---

For now I just used gulp to copy every .json file in the src folder over to the the respective dist/** folder.

But still find it strange typescript doesn't have something included for it..

Comment: Are you rebuilding every few seconds?  AJAX is probably your best solution, here.

Comment: Not necessarily, its just a build setup for dev. But the project includes .ts files, that may or may not be there, and may or may not have a (valid) config.json file.. (Its a project where you can write typescript modules in a browser, and upload them to a custom dir (where the .ts/.json files are)), and get compiled when bundled

Comment: I don't think this is possible with plain tsconfig. You will need some build script to do this. And placing these JSON files into a separate `data` folder is not an option? That's what I usually do. `src` only contains TypeScript files, `lib` contains the compiled JavaScript files and `data` contains raw data files. No need to copy these data files at all and you can still access them directly in the data directory with imports and/or readFile.

Comment: Often in Node.js applications a .json is needed. With [TypeScript 2.9, --resolveJsonModule](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#new---resolvejsonmodule) allows for importing, extracting types from and generating .json files.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should checkout [--resolveJsonModule](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html), it's a newer feature of typescript.